# Is it possible to create a program which establishes if a theorem given is demonstrable?

Tags: math, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, theorem

As written in the title, my question is about the possibility of creating a program which, given hypothesis and thesis, tries in some ways to demonstrate the theorem and print to user if it is demonstrable.

Comment: This was the reason the Prolog language was invented. There are several automatic theorem provers, but creating one from scratch might be a rather large endeavor. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving

Comment: This has been done with various degrees of success since the 1950s. Any reasonably comprehensive text on AI will discuss it. In general, it isn't possible to write a program that will always be able to determine if a theorem is demonstrable (a limitation which was been known since the 1930s, even before computers per se were invented).

Comment: Godel's theorem says it won't work for any self-referential system.

Comment: I think this question refers to the NP problem. Please have a look: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it depends on the theory you are taking into account. For example, if you consider FOL (first order logic) then this problem is known to be unsolvable (Entscheidungsproblem), while if you consider propositional logic, then the answer is yes (being it decidable).
More informations about decidability could be found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)#Some_decidable_theories